# сочетания клавиш ALT+F4 и CTRL+ALT+DEL

Tags: c#

Всем известно что сочетания клавиш <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> завершает работу программы,вернее отключает первое окно, а сочетания клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> вызывает диспетчер задач.

Можно ли написать код который при запущенной программе, не реагировал на эти сочетания клавиш, ну или выдавал сообщения в месаже бокс?

Comment: Как на счет перехвата процесса Диспетчер задач при вызове ctrl+alt+del?

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> лишь [посылает окну сообщение `WM_CLOSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Программа может реагировать на это сообщение закрытием окна, а может и не реагировать.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> обрабатывается системой и приложениям не посылается. Для того, чтобы вмешаться в его работу, вам придётся, боюсь, спускаться на уровень драйвера клавиатуры.

---

По поводу Ctrl+Alt+Del, вот перевод [ответа с serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/2914/137144):

> Ядро Windows (NT) устроено таким образом: оно резервирует оповещение об этой комбинации клавиш только для системного процесса Winlogon. Таким образом, если Windows работает правильно, то никакое пользовательское приложение не может обрабатывать эту комбинацию клавиш. Если бы оно смогло, оно бы смогло и показать юзеру фальшивый экран логина и таким образом перехватить его пароль ;)

---

Вот [эта статья](http://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/nftechsupt.web+WinBatch/Sending~Keystrokes+Sending~CTRL~and~Ctrl-Alt-Del~Keys.txt) говорит, что

> Сымитировать последовательность Ctrl-Alt-Del при помощи `SendKeys` не получится. Нажатие Ctrl-Alt-Del вызывает аппаратное прерывание, через прямой отдельный провод на клавиатуре.

То есть и перехватить его у Windows не получится.

Смиритесь.

Comment: драйвер клавиатуры не поможет, я проверял, разве что есть кокой то конкретный "финт ушами" о котором мне лично будет интересно узнать.

Comment: Хм. Интересно, правда ли это: http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/07/25/Securing-Windows-For-Use-As-A-Kiosk

Comment: Может я неправильно перевожу но там о назначении сочетания клавиш вместо CTRL+ALT+DEL и есть фраза "Delete the Scancode Map key from the registry and reboot to return your system to normal, just don't try to use CTRL+ALT+DEL to get there." к хукам по моему статья отношения не имеет.

Comment: @Mirdin: Угу. Но хуки ж не спускаются на уровень драйвера, они чисто юзермодовские.

Comment: есть такое понятие как юзермодовский драйвер, видимо на этот уровень они и спускаются, но это не "драйвер клавиатуры". З.Ы. Надо будет перечитать Они, что то я давно не тормашил эту тему, так что могу ошибатся

Comment: Спрошу-ка я специалиста по WinAPI, может, он вспомнит.

Comment: @VladD, ну как, спросил?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Спросил вот только что. Он говорит, что комбинация клавиш Ctrl-Alt-Del генерирует на уровне БИОСа (или самой клавиатуры, не помнит) специальное прерывание, отдельное только для этой комбинации клавиш. На него подписывается операционка, и реагирует соответствующим образом. Никаких юзеровских хуков нет, можно только проникнуть (драйвером) на нулевое кольцо и насильно отписать ОС от прерывания. Но это уже грязный хак, и не получит подписи от Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Не скажу про <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, но на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> поставить хук, насколько я знаю, нельзя, и соответственно никаких действий вы прицепить не сможете.

P.S. В любом случае это все не делается на c#, только си, только хардкор.

Comment: На уровень message loop'а вполне можно выйти и в C# (проще, конечно, в WinForms).

Comment: Да можно, но "геморойно", .Net -- это все таки немножко не о том, а во на уровень "драйвера клавиатуры", тут и плюсы не совсем подходят

Comment: Это да, там без чистого C не обойтись. Даже C++ не покатит, наверное.

Comment: @VladD, ЕМНИП там были какие то, сторонние, по моему, библиотеки, типа первого С++ еще с трансляцией, но они не всегда работали, но конкретно не скажу, "давно это было".

Answer (score 0):

Перехват <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4 && e.Alt) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Тест");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```